# phpStorm 7 Code Completion Issues

Tags: phpstorm, code-completion

Since updating to phpStorm 7 for OSX, I cannot get code completion for HTML to stop.

For example, if I type class=, as soon as I hit =, two double quotes are injected.  How can this be stopped?  Is this a bug?  I've unchecked everything under Preferences > Editor > Smart Keys and Code Completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to disable this feature:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113332#comment=27-612047

If you go to Preferences -> IDE Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys
and untick the box marked "Automatically add quotas for attribute value", you will be back to normal (non-frustrating) behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9749). It will be [possible to disable this behavior](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113332#comment=27-612047) in the future versions.